# validate first or before controller logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, express-validator

I want to create an Express REST API and want to validate the request params and  the request body.

I have a router file managing all the routes. When calling `localhost:3000/users` the router would forward to

```
app.use('/users', require(`./routes/users.js`));
```

Within that routes file I would manage all the user related routes

```
router.get('/', usersController.getAllUsers);
router.get('/:userId', usersController.getUserById);
router.post('/signup', usersController.signUp);
router.post('/signin', usersController.signIn);
router.post('/signout', authenticationCheck, usersController.signOut);
router.put('/:userId', authenticationCheck, authorizationCheck, usersController.updateUserById);
router.delete('/:userId', authenticationCheck, authorizationCheck, usersController.deleteUserById);
```

As you can see some routes have an `authenticationCheck` which handles the session management with JSON web tokens. The `authorizationCheck` handles the permissions.

The controller itself would execute the real logic

```
exports.deleteUserById = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { userId } = req.params;

    // validate the userID here?

    // try to delete the user from the database
    // send a response
};
```

To make sure the params and body variables have a correct format I want to use the `express-validator` module. My question is when should I validate the request?

I could validate first

```
router.delete('/:userId', validation(arguments), authenticationCheck, authorizationCheck, usersController.deleteUserById);
```

where `validation(arguments)` would take some parameters for validation and send a `400` if something failed. This would be good to avoid unnecessary code execution but there is no authentication or authoization check before.

I also could validate before calling the controller logic

```
router.delete('/:userId', authenticationCheck, authorizationCheck, validation(arguments), usersController.deleteUserById);
```

to check the authentication and authorization first but maybe this would lead to unnecessary code execution.

Both approaches have the problem that the validation logic gets handled within the routes file. You would have to synchronize the required controller variables within the routes file and later on in the controller file.

Lastly I could call the controller first and launch the validation immediately.

What is the best practise here?

Comment: If the user is not authorized, I don't see the point of validating any argument of his request. So the second one seems logic to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to validate before authentication & authorization. It will be unnecessary work because if the user is not authorized, data won't be used and doesn't need to be checked. This is how Frameworks like MEAN or Sail works.
You should use the second solution.

For information, you can group your routes with http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router

If necessary, you can also use http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.param

```
// router.js
var Router = require('express').Router();

Router.use('/users', require('./routes/users.js');

module.exports = Router;


// ./routes/users.js
var Router = require('express').Router(),
      auth = [authenticationCheck, authorizationCheck];

Router.param('userId', usersController.param);

Router.route('/')
    .get(usersController.getAllUsers);

Router.route('/:userId')
    .get(usersController.getUserById)
    .put(auth, usersController.updateUserById)
    .delete(auth, usersController.deleteUserById);

Router.route('/signup')
    .get(usersController.signUp);

Router.route('/signin')
    .get(usersController.signIn);

Router.route('/signout')
    .get(authenticationCheck, usersController.signOut);

module.exports = Router;
```